# How to detect precise depth in Intel Realsense D435 depth image

Tags: realsense

This is my first time to use D435 depth image to detect object distance. As I know, we can use Realsense SDK `depthframe.getDistance(x, y)` to get point(x,y) distance. However, the distance seems not correspond to depth image.

For example, I detect the red point(260, 300) in [image: Pic1] and get the correct distance 0.747m and the body part in depth image is blue color because it is closed to the camera.

But when I sit down, the corresponded distance of red point(260, 300) in [image: Pic2] shows 5.17m and the point still on my body. I don't know why D435 detects the wrong distance since its depth image still shows blue color in my body part. Any good suggestion to improve the precision of depth distance.

Comment: Are your depth and colour images aligned? A pixel in the colour image won't correspond directly to a pixel in the depth image without alignment. Check out the `align` processing block if not - there is sample code using it for most (if not all) of the wrappers on the librealsense repo.

Comment: Yes, I have aligned depth image to color image.